# Customize Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In routes.rb i've declared:

```
resources :photos
```

How can i map the /photos/new route with /admins/photos/new? With namespaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right. You can use:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :photos
end
```

Answer (score 2):

See Chapter 2.6 of [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

> You may wish to organize groups of controllers under a namespace. Most commonly, you might group a number of administrative controllers under an Admin:: namespace. You would place these controllers under the app/controllers/admin directory, and you can group them together in your router:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```